# nginx authentication from external service

Tags: authentication, nginx, post, reverse-proxy, access-token

My goal is to enable access on one (static) web page/folder only to authenticated users.
[auth_basic](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access-auth-basic/) is NOT option.

There are 2 servers: nginx (contains http,css and javascript) and REST server (doing authentication and provides secure content).
REST server provides access token.

On www.somesite.com/secret (hosted by nginx) should access only authenticated users.
I have tried something similar to this https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access-auth-request/

this is my config example:

```
location /secret/ {
           auth_request        /restauth;
           auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
    }
    location /restauth/ {
        internal;
        proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }
```

With this, only GET request is sent, REST service support only POST.

How can I send POST with access token, and with code 200 to allow access to content of /auth folder?

Another interesting thing I found is [nginscript](https://www.nginx.com/blog/launching-nginscript-and-looking-ahead/), but this simple example from this site doesn't work to me.